# Check Multiple Roles

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

With discord.js in Visual Studio Code, how do I make this code check multiple roles?

```
case "getkey":
    let modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Admin");
    if(message.member.roles.has(modRole.id)) {
      message.author.sendMessage("Insert message here")
    } else {
      return message.reply("you do not have permission to use this command!")
    }
  }
```

I want to know how to make it so this code checks 2 roles instead of just one.

```
let modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Admin");
```

Where it says "Admin", I've been trying to add like ("name", "Admin" + "Creator"); But it doesn't work, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another variable called `creatorRole` or something. Also, why did you even try doing `("name", "Admin" + "Creator");`? A string + another string just equals the two put together. `("name", "AdminCreator");` is what it would look like. Anyways,

```
let modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Admin");
let creatorRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Creator");

if(message.member.roles.has(modRole.id) || message.member.roles.has(creatorRole.id)) {
```

Something like that. Also, `sendMessage` should be deprecated. Simply use `send` instead.